# More Details when copying with Nautilus

Tags: ubuntu

Is there a way to show more details when copying in Ubuntu?

For instance I would like to see the current file.

[image]

Comment: Not possible at the moment. I believe it is in the wishlist already. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/799601